# use switch in foreach to get just one string (in php)

Tags: php, foreach, switch-statement

i have an array with more depths and i want to get the strings to use with switch...

this is my code, but the switch always gives me all cases, but i want to break the loop if case one "Ware zugestellt" is true...

```
foreach( $orderresult['status_history'] as $result ) {
   $comment = $result['comment'];

    switch( $comment ) {
        case "Ware zugestellt":
            echo "Ware zugestellt";
            break;  
        case "Ware in Versand":
            echo "Ware in Versand";
            break;                          
        case "Ware am Lager":
            echo "Ware am Lager";
            break;      
   }
}
```

Comment: what is the programming lang?

Comment: really sorry, this is php

Comment: To break out of the loop from the case block, you can use [`break 2;`](http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.break.php) in PHP. Is that what you need?

Comment: Thanks to Karsten, thats the solution

Answer (score 0):

In reference to @Kartsen Koop:

[Use break 2;](http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.break.php)